# How does heat and/or boiling remove vitamin C?

Tags: heat, food-chemistry, oxidation-state

The www is full of crackpot claims about how various food treatments alter their nutrition content and it makes finding actual science very difficult.

I am specifically interested in the vitamin C content of orange juice.
From an answer I received in Biology SE (referencing [Hodgins et al. 2002](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2621.2002.tb09543.x/abstract)), pasteurisation of orange juice is unlikely to reduce the vitamin C content by more than 20%. This tallies with what I have been able to find on the reduction of vitamin C in milk by pasteurisation.

My question is twofold:

(i) What are the processes at work which remove some vitamin C during pasteurisation? Is it just the heat? What is the mechanism?

(ii) If I were to *boil* orange juice for 10 minutes or so, would that remove much more vitamin C and if so, why?

Comment: Rob, see [this](http://nopr.niscair.res.in/bitstream/123456789/14572/1/IJBT%2011%283%29%20309-313.pdf).

Comment: @MARamezani Thanks. That is useful. It looks like the half life of the vitamin C in this study is of order hours at temperatures of 70-90 Celsius.